# how can I shorten php truncate function?

Tags: php, regex

For the situation where I need to check if string doesn't exceed given length 
and if it does then truncate and add ellipsis I usually use function as follows
but was wondering if one couldn't do it in one line instead, preg_replace maybe ?

```
function truncate($str, $length){

    if (strLen($str) > $length) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, $length) . ' ...';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: With a dynamic `$length` value I don't think so. With a static length, you can just use your substring line.

Comment: Why do you care if you do it in one line?  Do you think it will make some sort of difference in how fast your program runs.  It probably won't unless you are calling truncate thousands of times.  Use a profiling tool like XDebug if you're wanting to find out what parts of your code are slow.

Comment: You want a truncated truncate?  Seriously though, there's nothing wrong with what you've got.  It works and it's fairly self-explanatory.  Don't worry too much about shaving down a function that's already this short. Regex tends to be indecipherable in all but the simplest cases.

Comment: Oh it's not performance issue, it's rather wish to make beautiful code.

Comment: Beautiful and regex aren't words that really belong in the same sentence :)

Comment: This question better fits to [codereview.se] IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re looking for a regular expression solution:

```
function truncate($str, $length) {
    return preg_replace('/(.{'.(int)$length.'}).+/s', '$1 ...', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With an inline if:

```
return strLen($str) > $length ? substr($str, 0, $length) . ' ...'  : $str;
```

Comment: Use &hellip; instead of '...'